# Response con caracteres especiales en xml

Tags: xml, angulajs

Estoy tratando de hacer una petición `get` a un web service usando el modulo `$http` de `angularjs`, mi código es el siguiente, (esta dentro de un factory):

```
 getCurrentPositionByClientName: function(){
     var deferred = $q.defer();
     console.log("getbyclientename");

     $http({ 
         method: 'GET',
         url: 'http://url-webservice.com/etc/etc',
         headers: { 
           'Content-Type': "application/xml"
         } 
    }).then(function(result){
       deferred.resolve(result);
    }, function(error){
       deferred.reject(error);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

hasta aquí todo bien, hace la conexión y la petición bien, el problema que tengo es que me esta regresando el response en formato xml en teoria, pero con caracteres especiales como lo siguiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://www.tempuri.org/">
&lt;NewDataSet&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;ItemName&gt;108&lt;/ItemName&gt;
    &lt;ItemID&gt;37&lt;/ItemID&gt;
    &lt;IMEI&gt;207728640&lt;/IMEI&gt;
    &lt;ActualDate&gt;2017-08-02T15:44:09-06:00&lt;/ActualDate&gt;
    &lt;Lat&gt;24.055410999999999&lt;/Lat&gt;
    &lt;Lon&gt;-110.288417000000000&lt;/Lon&gt;
    &lt;Direction&gt;0.00&lt;/Direction&gt;
    &lt;Speed&gt;0.0240&lt;/Speed&gt;
    &lt;Cause /&gt;
    &lt;TriggerValue /&gt;
    &lt;EntityType&gt;VEHICLE&lt;/EntityType&gt;
    &lt;IgnitionStatus&gt;1&lt;/IgnitionStatus&gt;
  &lt;/Table&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;ItemName&gt;113&lt;/ItemName&gt;
    &lt;ItemID&gt;39&lt;/ItemID&gt;
    &lt;IMEI&gt;207224564&lt;/IMEI&gt;
    &lt;ActualDate&gt;2017-08-02T15:47:58-06:00&lt;/ActualDate&gt;
    &lt;Lat&gt;24.157910999999999&lt;/Lat&gt;
    &lt;Lon&gt;-110.312152000000000&lt;/Lon&gt;
    &lt;Direction&gt;128.00&lt;/Direction&gt;
    &lt;Speed&gt;10.6840&lt;/Speed&gt;
    &lt;Cause /&gt;
    &lt;TriggerValue /&gt;
    &lt;EntityType&gt;VEHICLE&lt;/EntityType&gt;
    &lt;IgnitionStatus&gt;2&lt;/IgnitionStatus&gt;
  &lt;/Table&gt;
&lt;/NewDataSet&gt;
</string>
```

Mi pregunta es: ¿Como puedo hacer que en vez de mostrar los caracteres especiales me muestre el `<` y `>` correctamente? o es necesario hacer una conversión o hay algún problema con mi `Content-type` al realizar la petición?

Answer (score 1):

Bueno no encontré problemas en el `content-type` asi que, lo que procedí a hacer fue remplazar los caracteres especiales una vez que el response llegará, usando el método `replace` un procedimiento almacenado y el carácter que quería que agregará. El código quedo de la siguiente manera:

```
var xml = data.data;

xml = xml.replace(/(&lt;)/g, "<");
xml = xml.replace(/(&gt;)/g, ">");

console.log(xml);
```

y en la consola queda de la siguiente manera:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://www.tempuri.org/">
<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <ItemName>108</ItemName>
    <ItemID>37</ItemID>
    <IMEI>207728640</IMEI>
    <ActualDate>2017-08-02T19:28:22-06:00</ActualDate>
    <Lat>24.046662000000001</Lat>
    <Lon>-110.299024000000000</Lon>
    <Direction>0.00</Direction>
    <Speed>0.0280</Speed>
    <Cause />
    <TriggerValue />
    <EntityType>VEHICLE</EntityType>
    <IgnitionStatus>1</IgnitionStatus>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <ItemName>113</ItemName>
    <ItemID>39</ItemID>
    <IMEI>207224564</IMEI>
    <ActualDate>2017-08-02T19:30:28-06:00</ActualDate>
    <Lat>24.102436999999998</Lat>
    <Lon>-110.312169999999990</Lon>
    <Direction>189.00</Direction>
    <Speed>34.0030</Speed>
    <Cause />
    <TriggerValue />
    <EntityType>VEHICLE</EntityType>
    <IgnitionStatus>2</IgnitionStatus>
  </Table>
</NewDataSet>
</string>
```

Y listo.